# Why doesn't this regular expression work in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I need to match (case insensitive) "abcd" and an optional trademark symbol

Regex: `/abcd(™)?/gi`

See example:

```
preg_match("/abcd(™)?/gi","AbCd™  U9+",$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

When I run this, `$matches` isn't populated with anything... Not even created as an empty array. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How is your file encoded?  PHP has got issues when it comes to unicode.  In your case, try using the escape sequence `\x99` instead of directly embedding the TM symbol.

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** I'm not a PHP guru. However, this seems to be an issue about character encodings. For example, your PHP file could be encoded as win-1252 (where ™ is encoded as `\x99`), and the data you are trying to match could be encoded as UTF-8 (where ™ is encoded as `\xe2\x84\xa2`), or vice versa (i.e. your file is UTF-8 and your data is win-1252). Try looking in this direction, and give us more information about what you are doing.

Comment: I don't mind if I lose reputation or the "chosen" answer status, really. I just would like to remind people that "up/downvoting" means "that was helpful/not helpful in relation to the question", not "I like/don't like your answer" or similar. And when you downvote, leave a comment why. It's proper.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it has something to do with the literal trademark symbol.

You'll probably want to check out how to use [Unicode with your regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html), and then embed the escape sequence for the [trademark symbol](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2122/index.htm).

Answer (score 2):

It was a combination of things... this was the regex that finally worked:

```
/abcd(\xe2\x84\xa2)?/i
```

I had to remove `/g` modifier and change the tm symbol to `\xe2\x84\xa2`.